# Replace certain character outside of XML code

Tags: xml, search, replace

Here is my question: I want to replace all instances of a forward-slash / OUTSIDE the original XML Code in <>

```
<format>Zefania XML Bible Markup Language</format>
<identifier>NeÜ</identifier>
    <subject />
<type />
<coverage />
```

```
<VERS vnumber="1">Was soll das Toben der Völker? / Was soll ihr sinnloser Plan?</VERS>
  <VERS vnumber="2">Die Großen der Welt lehnen sich auf. / Sie tun sich zusammen gegen Jahwe. / Gegen seinen Messias gehen sie an:<NOTE type="x-studynote">Wird im Neuen Testament von der Gemeinde in Jerusalem zitiert: Apostelgeschichte 4,25-26.</NOTE></VERS>
  <VERS vnumber="3">"Los, wir zerreißen die Fessel, / befreien uns von ihrem Strick."<BR art="x-p" /></VERS>
```

So it should look like (for example):

```
<VERS vnumber="1">Was soll das Toben der Völker? Was soll ihr sinnloser Plan?</VERS>
```

The "/" removed after "Völker" but not in the Code element .
I'm using Notepad++ but am open to other solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

If your text sample is accurate, you should search for / preceded and followed by a space. In HTML and XML code, / never is followed by space.

So:

Search for " / " (space / space)
Replace with " " (single space)

If your editor understands regular expressions you can search for one or more spaces, /, one or more spaces.